# Convert float to nvarchar keeping decimal variable part

Tags: sql-server, format

I have a problem converting float to string but t-sql returns it with scientific format.

Example:

```
declare @amount float
set @amount=5223421341.23
print cast(@amount as nchar(20))
```

returns "5.22342e+009"

Well I tried the function STR but there is the point: I don't know how many decimals could have the float and I don't want to round it.

There is a way to return the float as nchar with the same precision as float is declared?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Apparently not.   Is there some reason you can't use `Decimal` instead of `float`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the decimals places.  The below code shows that the decimal value is distorted and I cant find a way around it.  If there was a way to determine the precision of the float then the result could be rounded to a correct value.

With an unknown precision, I have yet to find a solution.

```
Declare @Amount float
Set @Amount=5223421341.23

Select LTrim(RTrim(Str(@Amount, 1000, 1000)))
```

Produces : `5223421341.2299995000000000`

Based on what I am reading floats are only approximations by definition so this may be the best you can get.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx

http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/F/floating_point_number.html

> Note that most floating-point numbers a computer can represent are
>   just approximations. One of the challenges in programming with
>   floating-point values is ensuring that the approximations lead to
>   reasonable results. If the programmeris not careful, small
>   discrepancies in the approximations can snowball to the point where
>   the final results become meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(float_TSQL);k(sql13.swb.tsqlresults.f1);k(sql13.swb.tsqlquery.f1);k(MiscellaneousFilesProject);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true), the best method in SQL is likely to use the [STR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) function.

```
declare @amount float
set @amount=5223421341.23
print str(@amount,20,6)
print convert(VARCHAR(50),rtrim(ltrim(str(@amount,20,6))))
```

This seems like it would cover most scenarios, but you need to find out the max and min values in your data set and also the max precision.

Comment: This will not work as he does not know the precision.  Change your 6 to 8 in the str function and you will have the same problem as I am having...

Comment: But if he knows he doesn't have any floats with more precision than 6, all is good. This could probably be established as truth by summing the field and the converted field and seeing if they are equal

Comment: Since floats are not exact, he is already rounding. He just doesn't realize it. That is why it is a poor practice to ever store numeric data that you want exact values for or intend to do calculations with as Float

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft SQL Server documentation, (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) `float` is a synonym for `float(53)`, and a `float(53)` has a precision of 15 digits.

But the 15 digits of precision say nothing about the exponent.  The exponent is about 300.  Which means that floats are capable of representing numbers containing about 300 zeros in them.  That's why scientific notation is indispensable.

If scientific notation was not a problem for you, 21 characters would be enough to hold 15 digits with a period among them, plus the trailing `e+999`.

But since scientific notation is an issue for you, then you have to have a text field large enough to hold numbers of the form 
0.0000000000000000000000000000000...00000000000000000000000000723237435435644
(that's almost 300 zeros followed by 15 digits)
and
377733453453453000000000000000000...00000000000000000000000000000000000000.0
(that's 15 digits followed by almost 300 zeros.)

So clearly, you are going to need some pretty huge text fields for what you are trying to do.

So, bottom line is, instead of looking for a solution to the problem as stated, I would recommend revising what you are trying to accomplish here.